# What is the difference between Q_ENUM and Q_ENUMS

Tags: c++, qt5, qmetatype

I just found multiple examples showing the usage of `Q_ENUM` and `Q_ENUMS` and looking into the definition of `Q_ENUM` showed me that it includes `Q_ENUMS` and other definitions.

I am not sure which one to write when using the enum in `Q_PROPERTY`, Qml/QtQuick, in signals/slots, QVariants and `qDebug()` output.

It seems like the `Q_ENUM` is the better one as it is defined using `Q_ENUMS`, but I'm just guessing here.

What exactly are the differences, why are there two at all and which one should be prefered?

Comment: [related](https://woboq.com/blog/q_enum.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [What's New in Qt 5.5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/whatsnew55.html) says:

> Added Q_ENUM to replace Q_ENUMS, which allows to get a QMetaEnum at compile time using QMetaEnum::fromType. Such enums are now automatically registered as metatypes, and can be converted to strings within QVariant, or printed as string by qDebug().

Answer (score 9):

Since Qt 5.5 `Q_ENUMS` is deprecated, replaced with the better `Q_ENUM`.

There is an example showing its use in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#a-simple-example):

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Priority priority READ priority WRITE setPriority NOTIFY priorityChanged)

public:
    MyClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyClass();

    enum Priority { High, Low, VeryHigh, VeryLow };
    Q_ENUM(Priority)

    void setPriority(Priority priority)
    {
        m_priority = priority;
        emit priorityChanged(priority);
    }

    Priority priority() const
    { 
        return m_priority; 
    }

signals:
    void priorityChanged(Priority);

private:
    Priority m_priority;
};
```

For further details on the reasons behind the move from `Q_ENUMS` to `Q_ENUM`, read [this blog entry](https://woboq.com/blog/q_enum.html)

Comment: Is the example supposed to illustrate a difference between `Q_ENUM` and `Q_ENUMS` or simply how `Q_ENUM` can be used?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye The example illustrates how to use `Q_ENUM`. `Q_ENUMS` has been deprecated, and should no longer be used.

Comment: The question was explicitly "what is the difference". Everyone knows that deprecated stuff shouldn’t be used anymore, so showing what wasn’t possible before, or what pitfall are avoided with the new method is a much better way to answer such question.

Comment: @Robin if you read the question it is clear OP didn't know it was deprecated, and was asking which to use and why. Stating one is deprecated should be sufficient to signal "don't use this one, use the other".

Comment: @SteveLorimer backward compatibility is a ***. Also in enterprise environment any "deprecated" stuff without explanation means "we will not pay you for changing code and we cannot afford testing, so we wait until it explodes". Which leads to "we will not upgrade".