# Using c++ enum in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtabbar

I have an `enum` that I use in qml

```
class SettingManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum BookKinds{
         BookKind1=0,
         BookKind2=1,
     };
     Q_ENUMS(BookKinds)
     Q_PROPERTY(BookKinds bookKind READ bookKind WRITE setBookKind NOTIFY bookKindChanged)

     explicit SettingManager(QObject *parent = nullptr);
     void setBookKind(BookKinds dkob);
     BookKinds bookKind();
  signals:
    void bookKindChanged();
};
```

in `main.cpp` I registerd `SettingManager`

```
qmlRegisterType<SettingManager>("Test",1,0,"SettingManager");
```

I use this in qml file

```
  onCurrentIndexChanged:
    {
        if(tbarBookKindForDisplay.currentIndex==0)
        {
           settingManager.bookKind=BookManager.BookKind1;
        }
        else if(tbarBookKindForDisplay.currentIndex==1){
            settingManager.bookKind=BookManager.BookKind2;
         }           
    }
```

when `CurrentIndex` of `TabBar` changes below error occurs:

> Error: Cannot assign [undefined] to int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You register the type as `SettingManager` but use it as `BookManager`. The correct code is:

```
settingManager.bookKind = SettingManager.BookKind1;
```

You should also use [`Q_ENUM` instead of `Q_ENUMS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46691754/904422).